# If $x$ is not nilpotent, how to prove there exists a prime ideal does't contain $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ideals

Actually, I find some explanation using Zorn's lemma and localization. However, our class doesn't include these until now. So can someone prove it in an easier way?

Comment: I don't think you can prove it without Zorn's lemma. The idea is that an ideal which is maximal with respect to the property of missing all powers of $x$ is prime.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27163/nilradicals-without-zorns-lemma.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can avoid Zorn's lemma (or some weaker assumption thereof), but you can avoid localization.

Suppose $x$ is not nilpotent and consider $S=\{x^n:n\ge0\}$. Consider the family of all ideals $I$ such that $I\cap S=\emptyset$. Such a family is not empty because it contains $\{0\}$.

Also, the union of a chain of ideals in this family is again an ideal in this family. By Zorn's lemma, we can choose a maximal member $P$. Let's prove $P$ is prime.

Suppose $ab\in P$, but neither $a$ nor $b$ belong to $P$. Then $aR+P$ and $bR+P$ are ideals properly containing $P$ and, by maximality, they intersect $S$. Suppose $x^m\in aR+P$ and $x^n\in bR+P$. Then $x^m=ar+u$ and $x^n=bs+v$, with $r,s\in R$ and $u,v\in P$. Now
$$
x^{m+n}=abrs+(bsu+arv+uv)\in P
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: What is the difference between $aR+P$ and $bR+P$ ?

Comment: @ldyhome One is the ideal generated by $a$ and $P$, the other by $b$ and $P$

Comment: Thank you very much. I remember the way of generating ideals by multiplication.